# Created a button to navigate to next PivotItem, how to go back to first PivotItem from the last PivotItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
private void appbariconNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timerPivot.SelectedIndex += 1;
    }

    private void appbariconPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerPivot.SelectedIndex -= 1;
    }
```

Problem is, if I press the Previous button from the first PivotItem, I will get an ArgumentException. Same thing if I press the Next button from the last PivotItem.

I currently have a changing number of PivotItem depending on the option chose by users, so it's inefficient for me to get the number of PivotItems from all those different scenarios.

Is there a way to get the total number of PivotItems that a Pivot has? Or is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: try timerPivot.SelectedIndex = (timerPivot.SelectedIndex + 1) % timerPivot.Items.Length;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is bad UI to create buttons to navigate from one page to another using buttons. What about swiping? Have you considered disabling it and restyling Pivot to make it appear as wizard (if that is what you are trying it to be)?

You can get the total number of Pivot items via the Items property. Simply do modular division with that number to keep the index number in range [0, Items.Length>.

I really hope that you are not abusing Pivot in any way.

Comment: Don't worry, I am aware of the Windows Phone design guideline, but the thing I'm currently developing requires a little bit more of a specialist approach to it.

I found out that I can get the total number of items by using the Pivot.Items.Count() method, I just need to subtract it by one to match the number with the array. :)

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Sorry about overly offensive comment :)